# Ensure SQL Server sensitive data authenticity

Tags: sql-server, security, encryption

I have an odd question that needs a creative answer.

I have code a program that writes sensitive data on a SQL Server Table with 3 columns.

Every time this program starts I need to check this data.

The problem is that I need a way to check that the data on this 3 fields was writed by my process and not manipulated nor copied externally or by other process.

So if the data on any of the 3 fields was modiffied externally, my code should not recognize the data. Also, if the data was copied from other server, neither should be recornized.

**What I have in mind:**

1) Create a secret private key with unique data from SQL Instance.

2) Create a binary field on the table.

3) When the data is witted, fill the binary field with PwdEncrypt function and private key as data.

4) When data is readed, use PwdCompare to check if the data on binary field match private key.

Now, how can I ensure that other fields are not modified?

I need this to work on several servers that use from SQL Server Express 2008 R2 to SQL Server Standard 2016

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your approach is pretty much correct, but you don't need anything asymmetric here, a simple HMAC will do.

When modifying any row of a table that requires data authenticity, concatenate the binary values of all fields that you want authenticated and run the final binary string through an HMAC with a secret key stored only with your process.

Do the same again when checking to see if the row is valid and compare the two resulting hashes using a time-safe check.  If they don't match, something has been tampered with.

Comment: Thanks, but you lost me with HMAC and the asymetric thing. Can you please elaborate a litte more? Do you mean I don't need to use SQL PWD's functions?

Comment: Also I found a problem with your approach: if two servers runs the same process, and the data on 3 fields are the same, both will generate the same hash, so data can be copied from one server to another and my process will read this data as valid. Or not?

Comment: I don't understand what part you don't understand.  Can you be more specific?

Comment: Simply give each running process a different HMAC key and they will no longer produce compatible hashes.

Comment: You said "you don't need anything asummetric". What do you mean with that.?

Comment: Asymmetric cryptography.  In your question you define the key you were going to use a "private key", implying asymmetric cryptography.  I'm saying that you don't need to use asymmetric cryptography here.